# Run program before Windows Login

Tags: windows, visual-studio

For example, if I created a simple program in Visual Studio and made it said "Hello World", would I be able to make it run before windows Login?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a program before a user logs in, you have to create a [windows service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx).

Visual Studio contains the [needed template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) to create the skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

I think not, because windows starts the tasks when the user make login into the account. But, you can create it in a way that appears when the user make login. :)

Comment: I've ran programs with command prompt without logging in before. So I think it's possible.

Comment: But you're wishing for a way that's automatic, right? If not, you're right.